# Match text surrounded by "{{" and "}}"

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a Regex which can do this :
My text :

```
"Blablabla {{ blabla1 }} blablablabla {{ blablabla2 {{ blabla3 }} }} blablabla"
```

What I want to extract :

```
"blabla1" and "blablabla2 {{ blabla3 }}"
```

Does anyone has an idea ?

I tried with : `"{{(.)*}}"`
but it returns `"blabla1"` and `"blabla3"`

Comment: You want it to return "blabla1" and "blablabla2 {{ blabla3 }}" only? Without "blabla3" ?

Comment: Yes. But if it returns "blabla3" also, it's alright too

Comment: For such recursive pattern writing a parser is easier when regex fails

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [balancing groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition) for counting and matching nested constructs like these. For example:

```
(?x) {{ ( (?: [^{}]+ | (?<open>{{) | (?<-open>}}) )* (?(open)(?!)) ) }}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks ! (I will read the whole doc about balancing groups also ;) )

Comment: @Qtax: Thank you very much.., i looking for solution for this question  " {{}} --> parenthesis ( ) "  (?x) \( ( (?: [^()]+ | (?<open>\() | (?<-open>\)) )* (?(open)(?!)) ) \)

Answer (score 2):

This has nesting, so it’s not a regular grammar. Some regex engines have extensions to handle brace matching, but in general the best way to do this is by simply scanning the string and accumulating output in a `List<string>` while keeping track of the nesting depth.

Comment: Which is exactly what balancing groups do for you. And if you want to make it more verbose you can always add comments in the expression. ;-)